# How to manually sort rows in a multi-index dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Yo, here's an example of a dataframe I'm currently working on

```
   a          b
   _____________
0  1        1.1                   
1  2        1.2
2  3        2.1
3  NaN      2.2
4  NaN      2.3
5  NaN      3.1
6  NaN      3.2
7  NaN      3.3
8  NaN      3.4
```

However, I wanted to sort this dataframe in a way that it can be displayed as shown below (getting rid of missing values & sorting it with clusters

```
   a          b
   _____________
   1        1.1                   
            1.2
     __________
   2        2.1
            2.2
            2.3
     __________
   3        3.1
            3.2
            3.3
            3.4
```

I don't really know how to encounter this properly. Any help is appreciated !

Comment: why not just update `a` with `b.astype(int)`?

Comment: @Chris because in fact the values are strings (titles a ("1.title") matched with its ("1.1/2/3 subtitles") b), thought that sorting them manually in this case could do the trick for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
df['new']= df['b'].astype('int')

df.loc[df['new'].duplicated(), 'new'] = ''


df = df.drop(columns=['a'])
df.columns=['b','a']

df.index =df['a']

df_final = df['b'].reset_index()  


print(df_final)
```

output#

```
   a    b
0  1  1.1
1     1.2
2  2  2.1
3     2.2
4     2.3
5  3  3.1
6     3.2
7     3.3
8     3.4
```